How to access sqlalchemy's asyncio extension?
I've tried to use sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio: I installed it using following command (like in official docs):
$ pip install sqlalchemy[asyncio]

But i got this error:
AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy.ext' has no attribute 'asyncio'

How to install sqlalchemy's asyncio correctly?
UPD: I've also installed sqlalchemy as follows: pip install sqlalchemy

What versions of Python and SQLAlchemy do you have installed?

You only need to install SQLAlchemy.
Then :
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncEngine

print(AsyncEngine)

works fine for me.
Adding
pip install sqlalchemy[asyncio]

is optional and only necessary if you have an unusual machine.
